# Unix : Head , Tail , Middle of all files recursively

Tags: shell

Requirement :

There might be multiple files within a folder . For Each File , i want to retrive Top10, Bottom 10 and Middle 10 of each file and dump into One File .

Example : 
Input Files : `APPLE.TXT, ORAGNE.TXT , BANANA.TXT`
Output File: `Final.TXT` which will contain Top 10, Bottom 10 , Middle 10  of each file Above.

Final.Txt  will have  :
Apple.txt
ABC
CDE
EFG
ORANGE.TXT
DEF
GEH
IJK

etc.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: What's your question? Is this just a homework dump?

Comment: show us till where you have done and where u have problem

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few pointers to get you started:

Use `head` to get the first ten lines:

```
head -10 file
```

To append the output of the command to a file, use `>>` e.g. `head -10 file >> output`

Use `tail` to get the last ten lines:

```
tail -10 file
```

Use `sed` to get the middle ten lines. You need to work out the line numbers first as shown below:

```
total=$(wc -l < file)
middle=$((total/2))
start=$((middle-4))
end=$((middle+5))
sed -n ${start},${end}p file
```

Of course, you should first check that your file has at least ten lines.